# Vagrant Homestead is not connecting with PostgresSql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, vagrant, homestead

While connecting psql in Vagrant Homestead I am getting the following error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and 
accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can anyone please share some pointers on where to look for errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to connect to a database hosted in the VM from your local machine, you need to forward the port in your Homestead.yaml config:

```yaml
ports:
  - send: 54320
    to: 5432
    protocol: udp
```

When Vagrant forwards a port to your local machine it needs first check that it's available, if you're running multiple VMs using PostgreSQL you likely are already using the port `54320`. It attempts to correct these and finds an available port to use, usually starting from 2000. If you're intending to use multiple VMs at the same time, I'd recommend forwarding to ports you expect will be available such as `54321`.

If you're trying to see what port Vagrant has corrected to, it shows you in the `forwarded ports` section in the logs during `vagrant up`.

Don't forget to `vagrant reload --provision` after making changes to your Homestead.yaml config.

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused means that the port you are trying to connect to is not actually open.
Just have re-read on documents https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#ports
so I think to try 54320 port in your local machin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).